# Error when check exist key in a array php?

Tags: php

I have a sample code:

```
$array1 = ("key1", "key3");
$array2 = ("value1", "value3");
$array = array_combine($array1, $array2);
if(!isset($array["key2"])) {
   $array["key2"] = "value2";
}
```

But result is error, how to fix it

```
array("key1"=>"value1", "key2"=>"value2", "key3"=>"value3");
```

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php to learn how to initialize arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to specify that you wish that the arguments currently assigned to `$array1` and `$array2` are to be used as arrays.

```
$array1 = array ("key1", "key3");
$array2 = array ("value1", "value3");
```

---

#### Full example

```
$array1 = array ("key1",     "key3");
$array2 = array ("value1", "value3");

$array  = array_combine($array1, $array2);

if(!isset($array["key2"])) {
  $array["key2"] = "value2";
} 

print_r ($array);
```

```
Array
(
    [key1] => value1
    [key3] => value3
    [key2] => value2
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should define array1 and array2 like this :

```
$array1 = array("key1", "key3");
$array2 = array("value1", "value3");
```

See [this fiddle](http://codepad.viper-7.com/KNfzbj).

And if you want them to be ordered, just use [ksort](http://php.net/ksort):

```
ksort($array);
// var_dump($array); output:
// array(3) { ["key1"]=> string(6) "value1" ["key2"]=> string(6) "value2" ["key3"]=> string(6) "value3" }
```

See [this fiddle](http://codepad.viper-7.com/r2pttg).